# Docker COPY command not copying a specific file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a folder `dist` having  `config.yaml, configuration.d.ts ,configuration.js and configuration.map` files inside. The issue is all files are copied to container except the `config.yaml` file.

On debugging I found, If I write `COPY dist dist` before the line `FROM abcd.com/baseos/node:buster-14.15.4-1` the config.yanl works. But I write `COPY dist dist` after the line `FROM abcd.com/baseos/node:buster-14.15.4-1` it doesn't copy the config.yaml file but copies all other files `configuration.d.ts ,configuration.js and configuration.map`

The command to build my Dockerfile is below:-

`docker build -t drs:1.0.0 -f . /srs/sync-data`

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM abcd.com/baseos/node:buster-14.15.4-1 AS buildcontainer

COPY src src
COPY config config
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY tsconfig.build.json .
COPY .eslintrc.js .
COPY .prettierrc .

RUN npm ci && \
    npm run build && \
    rm -rf node_modules && \
    npm ci --production

FROM abcd.com/baseos/node:buster-14.15.4-1

ARG SERVICEVERSION=0.0.0-snapshot
ENV SERVICEVERSION=$SERVICEVERSION

COPY --from=buildcontainer dist dist
COPY --from=buildcontainer node_modules node_modules
COPY package.json .
CMD npm run start:prod
```

Comment: Include the contents of your `.dockerignore` file

Comment: I'd normally expect `npm run build` to regenerate the contents of the `dist` directory.  Does it recreate the `dist/config.yaml` file?

Comment: I don't have any .dockerignore file

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using nestjs, I didn't copied over `nest-cli.json` in dockerfile. My nest-cli.json had below config:-

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [{"include": "../config/*.yaml", "outDir": "./dist/config"}]
}
```

which tells the nest compiler to put it into dist folder.

Once I added below line in Dockerfile, it worked.

`COPY nest-cli.json .`